# FabricJS ApplyFilter is slow on large images

Tags: fabricjs

Taking a very basic stock example such as the redify filter, with a large image (1200x1024) I was trying to determine why it takes (what I think) is too long. After some investigating, I find that the delay occurs in fabricjs::ApplyFilter, where replacement.src = canvasEl.toDataURL('image/png'); (line 17933 in 1.6.2). That take a long time, even compared to the complete pixel run through by the filter.

Is there some way around this? Can I do something differently to speed up the process? TIA

Comment: facing the same issue, its sad this question remains unanswered. Were you able to solve the issue?